# JQuery -- List items to slide onto the screen when the user scrolls to them

Tags: jquery, animation, text

I've been working with this:

```
<head>
 <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(
         function() {
             $("#text").hide();
             $("#text").html("Words!").slideDown('slow');
     });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="text"></div>
```

I'd like to slide in list items when the screen reaches that point.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Put your slide down in a scroll event

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $("#text").html("Words!").slideDown('slow');
});
```